# Update Data in JcomboBox with database data after inserting new data

Tags: java, swing

I am having trouble getting a JComboBox refreshing when i close another Jframe.

What I am after is the ComboBox Refreshing its data from the data in the database and showing it. Problem is the new data entred is entred via another page.

Examples:

[image: Frame where the Combobox needs to refresh after other frame has inserted data. But it needs to not delete already entred data into the program]
[image: Frame where the data is inserted to the database.]

Insert for Jframe Codigo postais:

```
LigacaoBD ligaDB = new LigacaoBD();
     Connection con = ligaDB.obterLigacao();

     String query=null;
     Statement xpto;

     try {
        xpto= con.createStatement();




      xpto.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO codigospostais (cod_postal, localidade) VALUES ('" + this.jCodPostal.getText() + "', '" + this.jtflocalidade.getText() +"')");
    }

    catch (SQLException sqle) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sqle + "Erro no query");
        //System.out.println("Erro no query");
    }

     ligaDB.fecharLigacao(con);
```

Comment: For better help sooner please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make sure that the postal code selection is updated with the latest available postal codes when you save a new postal code while a client creation form is open, you can just add a listener to the drop down button that queries the updated list every time you click the button.

Also, creating a query string like this is incorrect:

```
xpto.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO codigospostais (cod_postal, localidade) VALUES ('" + this.jCodPostal.getText() + "', '" + this.jtflocalidade.getText() +"')");
```

This makes your code susceptible to SQL Injection. Try reading up on [PreparedStatements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for a better solution.